# Java DatagramSocket - send multiple values in one packet

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I am trying to send multiple value in one packet over UDP. I use `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write the bytes in byte array and `ByteArrayInputStream` to read those values on the server side. The problem is that the maximum value that I can write to `ByteArrayOutputStream` which can be correctly read is 255 but I need to send greater values. Here is my code for Server side

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private boolean running;
    private byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    public Server() throws SocketException {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(4445);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                DatagramPacket packet
                        = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);

                ByteArrayInputStream bInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);

                System.out.println(bInput.read());
                System.out.println(bInput.read());


            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and for the client side

```
public class Main {

    private static InetAddress ip;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Runnable server = new Server();
        new Thread(server).start();

        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
        byte[] data = new byte[1024]; // Max length

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        packet.setAddress(ip);
        packet.setPort(4445);

        ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        as.write(5);
        as.write(300);
        packet.setData(ba.toByteArray());

        ds.send(packet);
  }
}
```

So I can get number 5 from `ByteArrayInputStream` but any value greater than 255 revived incorrectly.

Comment: You are sending multiple values, the problem is the `ByteArray` which works with bytes. `as.write(300)` actually converts `300` to `byte` and writes `44`

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, but then how can I send then multiple values in one packet with correct values?

Comment: Wrap the `ByteArrayOutputStream` in a `DataOutputStream`: then you can send any primitives you like. At the receiver, wrap the `ByteArrayInputStream` in a `DataInputStream`. NB It should be `ByteArrayInputStream bInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf, 0, packet.getLength());`

Comment: @user207421 can you please post a code example if possible?

Comment: I've already provided about half of it. Just look up the Javadoc. It's not hard. NB `data` in the sender is futile. It would be better to do the `ByteArrayOutputStream` part first and then `new DatagramPacket(ba.toByteArray(), ba.toByteArray().length, ip, 4445);` and avoid all the `set`s completely.